# Text-decoration:none and text-shadow conflict

Tags: google-chrome, css, text-decorations

Even though `text-decoration` is **none**, applying a `text-shadow` to a link appears to - on hover - show the shadow of an invisible underline (Chrome only, Firefox ok). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xPYGd/17/).

HTML:

```
<a class="bill-area" href="#" title="Watch">
    <div class="watch"><h2>Watch</h2></div>
</a>​
```

CSS:

```
a                 {color:#00C; text-decoration:none}
a:hover           {text-decoration:underline}
a:active          {color:#F00;}
.bill-area        {width:580px; height:300px;display:inline-block; background:#eee}
.watch            {position:absolute; top:60px; left:200px; display:block;}
.watch h2         {text-align:center; color:#333; text-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6),0 2px 1px #154C77;}
.bill-area:hover div h2  {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment out the text-shadow to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is doing what is expected of it, showing the shadow of the underline. Rather than adding an underline to the text, why not make use of the *border-bottom* property? http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/2YC2M/ - replace a:hover { text-decoration: underline; } with:

```
a:hover div h2 {border-bottom:1px solid #00C;}
```

This will remove the text shadow as the border is not part of the text, unlike the underline which is considered part of the text.

If you don't want any underline, text-decoration or shadow, then remove this line:

```
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: why would it be different between browsers? there is no underline and chrome seems to add the shadow whereas firefox doesn't.

Comment: Not sure but there are even differences between Chrome on a PC and a Mac... what effect are you after? Underline with no shadow or no underline and no shadow?

Comment: The effect I need is text has shadow but no underline (or shadow thereof) on hover. I'm just surprised the `.bill-area:hover div h2  {text-decoration:none;}` isn't doing the trick!

Comment: It's showing an underline because the you've specified that the <a> tag should have an underline on hover, remove that and the underline will be gone completely. The shadow too!

Comment: Playing around it with some more showed that `.bill-area:hover div h2 {text-decoration:none;}` wasn't producing the expected behavior because of the descendant tags. Using a simple `.bill-area:hover {text-decoration:none;}` worked.

Comment: I guess I didn't think about the case that a:hover is a global style, but yeah, that would do the same thing for that specific element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
  <style type="text/css">
  a                 {color:#00C; text-decoration:none}
a:hover           {text-decoration:none}
a:active          {color:#F00;}
.bill-area        {width:580px; height:300px;display:inline-block; background:#eee}
.watch            {position:absolute; top:60px; left:200px; display:block;}
.watch h2         {text-align:center; color:#333; text-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6),0 2px 1px #154C77;}
.bill-area:hover div h2  {text-decoration:none;}
  </style>
```

Comment: i need the rest of the links to underline on hover